# Search Button VBA : Find values in Excel cell and populate fields based upon finding results. as well as listing duplicates as list

Tags: excel, vba

I am really new at this so excuse my ignorance.

I have created a Excel vba for a friend listing cars etc.
I am now able to search for any item in the sheet - could not before.
I would like to be able to search for an item but upon duplicates list them please se my (from Internet) code below

thanks

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    Dim iSearch As Long, i As Long
    Dim jSearch As Long, j As Long

    iSearch = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    jSearch = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

    For i = 1 To iSearch
        For j = 1 To jSearch

            If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, j)) <> Trim(txtsearch.Text) And i = iSearch And j = jSearch Then
                MsgBox ("Invalid data")
                txtsearch.Text = ""
            End If
            txtsearch.SetFocus

            If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, j)) = Trim(txtsearch.Text) Then
                txtref.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
                txtmanufacturer.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
                txtmodel.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
                txtyear.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
                txtvin.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5)
                txtengine.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6)
                txtcolour.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7)
                txtkm.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)
                txttransmission.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9)
                txtfuel.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: List them where/how? You can't do that with a bunch of textboxes - you'd need something like a listbox.

Comment: What about using a Pivot Table? They are great at filtering and displaying data and can group rows together based on shared data. They are also user friendly for people who want to re-sort or re-filter the results but don't want to write a custom macro to do it.

Comment: Hi Tim, I do have a list box where all the detail is listed just not sure how to list only the searched items.  Thanks

Comment: Toddleson,  That is a good Idea I will add that as well.  First prize would be to list the searched items in the listbox though thanks